# Starting vimtex plugin from within a vim session

Tags: plugin-system

I use [Vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/doc/vimtex.txt) to edit LaTeX documents in Vim. If I open an existing `.tex` file, the Vimtex plugin will be initiated automatically. However, if I create a new `.tex` file, there's no way to initiate the plugin. I have to start a new vim sessions altogether, which is quite annoying when there are multiple tabs open. e.g.

```
cd ~ && vim delme.tex
```

starts a vim session without initiating the plugin. Similarly if I do `:tabe delme2.tex` from within that session.

How do I start up the Vimtex plugin (or any other plugin) from within a Vim session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because only by the `.tex` file extension, Vim doesn't know whether a file is of type LaTeX or Plain TeX and it defaults to the latter.

The filetype detection logic is defined in function [`dist#ft#FTtex()` from script `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/dist/ft.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/autoload/dist/ft.vim#L644,L648), which is preceded by the following comments:

> Choose context, plaintex, or tex (LaTeX) based on these rules:
>
> 1. Check the first line of the file for `%&<format>`.
> 2. Check the first 1000 non-comment lines for LaTeX or ConTeXt keywords.
> 3. Default to `plain` or to `g:tex_flavor`, can be set in user's vimrc.

This explains why a new blank file will default to using Plain TeX, which is most likely not what you want.

You can override that manually with `:set ft=tex` after Vim detects your file incorrectly. This should fix it for the current open buffer. Also note that the names used for the `'filetype'` setting are `ft=tex` for LaTeX and `ft=plaintex` for Plain TeX.

Another option is to either enter a first line with `%&latex` or similar (rule #1 above.) Or enter a keyword recognized as LaTeX, among which are `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` and `\begin{...}` (rule #2 above.) Using either of the two, save the file with `:w` and re-read it with `:e`. While re-reading it, Vim will do filetype detection again and this time it should properly set `ft=tex` (for LaTeX) automatically for you.

Third possibly is, if you typically only edit LaTeX files and would like to make that the default (using rule #3), by appropriately setting the `g:tex_flavor` variable on your vimrc, with a line such as:

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

Once that setting has been loaded, then every new `*.tex` file (or an existing one that isn't detectable by rules #1 and #2) will default to using `ft=tex`, which means LaTeX.

Comment: Very thorough, thanks a lot. `:set ft=tex` is exactly what I was looking for! The options are equally as handy.